# Unresolved Reference in Visual Studio 2012 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

Is there a way to reference another database from my database project without directly referencing it?

For example, I want to be able to write something like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW View1
AS
  SELECT X FROM OtherDB.dbo.Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to add a database reference to your project. For VS2010 and lower DBProj files, you'll want to generate a dbschema file and add it as a database reference. For SSDT, you'll want to use a dacpac file. This works well for projects that are mostly static and you can even tailor them down to just include the objects that are relevant.

VS2010, 2008 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283%28v=VS.90%29.aspx has the documentation you'll need to export an existing database into a dbschema file. Place it somewhere your project can access it and add it as a "Database Reference".

SSDT - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=VS.103%29.aspx gives you the command line reference for generating a dacpac file. Once generated, place it somewhere your project can access it and add as a database reference.

I've got a blog post on this for SSDT here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

Comment: yes i am aware of this options but i just wanted to create view without any checking. i thought there must be a way to turn off this error

Comment: You can turn off the warnings for missing objects, but you may not be able to deploy without the reference. You can also add it as a post-deploy script, but it won't show up as something you can use in your project that way.

Comment: How do you turn off the warnings?

Comment: I had tried to create a DACPAC from the context Task menu in SSMS for this database and it kept failing.  After days of manually importing the db with its tens of thousands of objects, I stumbled onto your response here and tried the command-line tool.  Worked like a charm!  Now wondering why that worked and the SSMS approach did not.

Comment: Wish I knew for sure, but I went through similar exercises until I realized that the command line "just worked". :) Glad that you have a working reference now. And remember that it's just a renamed ZIP file if you ever need to edit it to tweak things, though once you have a working build you can just use the dacpacs from the builds.