# Can I remove unresolved reference error in Visual Studio, SQL Server project

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a view in my database project in Visual Studio.

But the source database name can change so I am keeping that in a variable and I am setting this variable to source database name in the pre-deployment script.

The problem which I am facing is that Visual Studio does not allow me to create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewName]
AS 
   SELECT * 
   FROM [$(SourceDatabaseName)].[dbo].[SourceTable]
```

It is showing an error:

> Error 1   SQL03006: View: [dbo].[ViewName] has an unresolved reference to object [$(SourceDatabaseName)].[dbo].[SourceTable].

I found a very similar question : [Unresolved Reference in Visual Studio 2012 Database Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193505/unresolved-reference-in-visual-studio-2012-database-project)

But there was no solution mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by including the view in the post deplyoment script, as VS does not compiles the post deployment script so the  `[$(SourceDatabaseName)].[dbo].[SourceTable]` part remains error free and the script was generated error free.